# Android cannot resolve method getActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity

```
    fileHippoWrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filehippo_wrapper2);
    fileHippoWrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(FinalChatActivity.this, "FileHippo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlAttachmentOptions.processLocationAction(getActivity(), null);

        }
    });
```

I'm not able  import function `processLocationAction` from another activity `AlAttachmentOptions` it says

> can't resolve method getActivity()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `getActivity()` method in Android Activity. This is just to indicate that you need to get reference of your activity here.

So instead of `getActivity()`, use `this` Or `FinalChatActivity.this`. It will work.

So your code will:

```
fileHippoWrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filehippo_wrapper2);
fileHippoWrapper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(FinalChatActivity.this, "FileHippo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlAttachmentOptions.processLocationAction(FinalChatActivity.this, null);

    }
});
```

Comment: I think use 'this' is wrong in the sense that 'this' is referring to the View.OnClickListener, not the activity itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`AlAttachmentOptions.processLocationAction(FinalChatActivity.this, null);`

Comment: @pcruizer if this is helpful with you. Please vote up and (or) mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Additional note on @TruongHieu's answer, `getActivity()` doesn't exist in `onClick(View view)`, so you can't just call getActivity() from there.

In order to get the activity of current Activity, you need to do the samething as Toast statement.

```
Toast.makeText(FinalChatActivity.this, "FileHippo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
AlAttachmentOptions.processLocationAction(FinalChatActivity.this, null);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: An anonymous inner class (`OnClickListener` here) can call methods from the scope/class where it was created. Calling `getActivity()` in there would be perfectly valid if this code were in a Fragment (I'd guess it was copied from an example that used Fragments). Just remove the first sentence and the answer is fine.

Comment: @TylerV, thanks for pointing it out. As you already make assumption that this code is valid only if it appeared in Fragment but we don't have such information from the code segment above. What is being told was the method getActivity() cannot be found, doesn't the first sentence make any sense?  cheers.